# Having 2 Application folders in macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, applications, catalina

I just installed Macos Catalina. After the update I did a check on what's new and I found something new which is a double / redundant "Applications[image]" folder. Usually the old Application folder is located in Disk / Users / Applications, but now there is also an Application folder in Disk / System / Volumes / Data / Applications.

My question is: can I deleted the old Application folder? Because it's consuming my hard disk. And if I delete the old application folder, can it disrupt the app's performance?

Comment: I know it wasn't asked, but for a temporary fix of spotlight, you can hide that folder in privacy tab of spotlight settings. (if it wasn't changed in catalina)

Comment: There is also /System/Applications which appears to be the actual location of the intrinsic apps from the system.  If you, for example, do a "Get Info" on one app from /Applications then do a "Get Info" on the same app from /System/Applications , the same Get Info window is just brought forward. With all this unnecessary complexity, no wonder there are so many problems with the latest OSs. The KISS engineering principle is a thing of the past at Apple.

Answer (score 5):

> Can I delete the old Application folder?

No, you should not.

I looks like one (`/Application`) is virtual folder for another (`/System/Volumes/Data/Applications`).

---

To **fix duplication in Alfred**, just type `reload` in it.

---

More context:

- https://superuser.com/questions/1454743
- https://www.alfredforum.com/topic/13121-duplicate-apps-in-results-1015-and-v4
- https://www.alfredforum.com/topic/13760-after-upgraded-to-catalina-applications-show-from-systemvolumesdataapplications-instead-of-applications

Comment: The 'Reload Alfred Cache' in Alfred worked for me, no more duplicates

Answer (score 1):

The /Applications folder is an illusion and not an actual APFS storage location. Due to firm links and special coding, it combines files from two distinct /Application type folders.

I linked to an excellent article as well as some Apple documentations in this similar but not identical question:

- [Is there a difference between launching an app from /Applications vs /System/Volumes/Data/Applications?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372904/is-there-a-difference-between-launching-an-app-from-applications-vs-system-vol)

Don’t delete it, instead adjust / patch your programs that aren’t aware of this new development or break due to this change in macOS Catalina 10.15