# Why does opening from the terminal in MacOS Catalina 10.15.7 fail?

Tags: terminal, finder, preview

From a terminal prompt, when I do:

```
open -a /Users/homer/Applications/Preview /Users/homer/Downloads/test.jpg
```

I get an error:

```
FSPathMakeRef(/Users/homer/Applications/Preview) failed with error -43.
```

But if I do:

```
open /Users/homer/Downloads/test.jpg
```

the image is opened in Preview just fine.

What is going on?

Comment: I’m puzzled why Preview.app is in ~/Applications and not where Catalina installed it?

Comment: Edited the question, thx

Comment: Great question +1  -  I’ll try to find time this weekend to reproduce it. Might just be sandbox restrictions or firmlinks assembling multiple application folders into one for Finder. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/372960/5472

Comment: For context, this was done on a Macbook Pro (Mid 2014) 1398A and was upgraded from Mojave to Catalina, so it wasn't done on a fresh Catalina install if that makes a difference.

Comment: `open -a /System/Applications/Preview.app file.png` works for me. Note the default install location of /System/Applications, and the `.app` extension, which I found I needed to include.