# Why is Preview.app in /Applications and not where Catalina installed it?

Tags: macos, finder, preview

Recently I upgraded from Mojave to Catalina 10.15.7. When going to "/Applications" in the Finder GUI, I see Preview.app. But if I cd /Applications in the terminal and do ls -lah, I don't see "Preview.app" listed in the directory contents.

What happened?

Comment: I wonder if these are relevant https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/372960/5472 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/372961/5472

Comment: The title says ~/Applications and the body says /Applications. Which is it?

Comment: Thank you, it's /Applications as in "cd /Applications" from a terminal prompt. I copy/pasted from somewhere else and missed that.

Comment: In Catalina and beyond, almost none of the apps that come with macOS are actually going to be in /Applications/ but they will appear to be in there, mostly because that's where people expect to find them. Safari is an exception because Safari can get updated separately than the entire OS.