# Terminal ls command does not list complete contents of /Applications

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, command-line, bash

In Terminal.app, I issue the following commands:

```
cd /Applications
ls
```

It lists many, but not all, of the apps that the Finder sees. The ones it appears to omit are all Apple, but it doesn't omit all Apple apps.

I've gone to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy and enabled Full Disk Access for `sh` and for `Terminal.app`. It does not change the behavior.

I've overridden the default `zsh` in favor of `bash`, but switching to zsh does not change the behavior.

Can anyone explain this or at least corroborate?

I'm running MacOS 12.2.1.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Applications in Finder is a mix of read only apps and user space apps](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/372960/5472) - terminal is not wrong, but Finder and graphical applications mix both so you see a unified folder when on disk there is not one folder that contains both sets of applications stored in two folders beneath /System

- [Having 2 Application folders in macOS Catalina](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/372349/)

Do you see all apps you expect from this command?

```
ls /Applications /System/Applications
```

Comment: And every user has their separate `Applications` folder, too (`~/Applications`). So the complete list might be `ls /Applications ~/Applications /System/Applications`.