# File duplication takes no disk space!

Tags: macos, filesystem

I have a question that's probably not asked too often, because it has little negative impact on the user. I can't find it on The Google anyway.

So this question is for the edification of the curious-minded.

In my production environment I manually backup often. I have noticed that when simply duplicating files, they don't take up as much space as they used to in older versions of MacOSX.

As an experiment (because I am a nerd) I attempted to fill my hard drive by copying large files. Duplicating files barely changed the "capacity" / "available" numbers at all.

The duplicates are there.

**Can someone explain this aspect of the OSX filing system** to me? It's absolutely amazing!

Details:

- not using Cloud
- MacBook Air ca. 2017
- MacOSX 10.14.6

Comment: Note that if you're duplicating files on the same volume, that's not a backup.

Comment: @benwiggy Understood. It's a backup *in situ,* not a proper backup to a secondary drive. I was calling it backup in terms of my own production system, not the Apple file system.

Comment: The concept you're looking for is _copy-on-write_.

Comment: Also [it's just macOS now](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS#macOS).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Apple File System (APFS) and Clones

Copying a file creates a clone of that file. Clones take very little space. Only when a clone is modified, is significant additional space required.

> ### [Clones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_File_System#Clones)
>
> Clones allow the operating system to make efficient file copies on the same volume without occupying additional storage space. Changes to a cloned file are saved as delta extents, reducing storage space required for document revisions and copies.[9] There is, however, no interface to mark two copies of the same file as clones of the other, or for other types of data deduplication.

See also iMore's [Apple File System (APFS): What you need to know](https://www.imore.com/apfs).

To understand how APFS works, see the [Apple File System Reference](https://developer.apple.com/support/apple-file-system/Apple-File-System-Reference.pdf).

Comment: Very nice! I suspected that some kind of system was in play like the one in the "Delta extents" link. Thank you, Graham, for providing this information on Clones.

Comment: I wonder how it works when you clone, then delete the original. Or, worse still, clone - then original gets corrupted/damaged and you try to copy your clone back.  I can see non-technical users getting rather annoyed at this.

Comment: @AleksG This is exactly my concern with this hidden behavior. Duplicating files on the same file system is common for temporary backups. And how does one know the files are linked if you duplicate and rename? And how many deltas are needed before a whole new file is just made?

Comment: With APFS, we need to change our behaviour and start copying to alternative volumes or physical drives. Copies on the same volume should not be considered safe guards against file corruption.

Comment: @Logarr there is no Apple provided friendly interface to examine the underlying state of files on APFS. I would not expect any. The trend with Apple is towards more abstraction in the file system. Look at Apple's decision with how the [Applications folder is handled in macOS 10.15](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372349).

Comment: @AleksG "I wonder how it works when you clone, then delete the original." Nothing interesting happens. The old reference to the data is destroyed, the new reference remains, and the underlying data is undisturbed.

Comment: @AleksG thats already a thing on Unix, it's called a link.   if you make a file called "foo", that is a filename entry in a directory pointing to a sequence of blocks on the disk.  If you go `ln foo bar` now "bar" is a filename entry in a directory **pointing to the same sequence of blocks**.  If an app opens "foo", that creates a third pointer, so if you delete both "foo" and bar" the sequence of blocks persists until the app is done.  Unix and MacOS already do this, classic example an iPhoto to Photos migration, new Photos directory is just plain links to files in the old iPhoto directory.

Comment: @Logarr "*And how does one know the files are linked if you duplicate and rename?*" You shouldn't care about it; it's implementation detail. Files should behave exactly the same except for taking less spaces.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica IMO link is different. Its behavior is explicit and specified, not like "clones" which is more like an optimization (think about `gcc -O3`) that shouldn't change the behavior. If you explicitly link two handles to one file (inode), then changing the file through any handle would update what other handles see. This doesn't seems to be the case for clones, which works more like Copy-on-Write.

Comment: @Harper I'm familiar with links. I am also painfully aware of what happens when the link target gets corrupted. A typical macos user may not realise that they are not creating a full backup copy when in fact they are creating a link.

Comment: @AleksG the apple clone isn't a link, but I suspect uses the link infrastructure. If A links to A' on creation, and clone B links to A' x diffs... If A is modified/corrupted, then A now links to A' x diffs.  A' can't be changed because B needs it.   So the question is whether A is corrupted or whether A' is corrupted, i.e. At what level of the filesystem the corruption occurs.

Comment: To understand how APFS works, see the [Apple File System Reference](https://developer.apple.com/support/apple-file-system/Apple-File-System-Reference.pdf).

Comment: @GrahamMiln can you clarify what this means? "no interface to mark two copies of the same file as clones of the other, or for other types of data deduplication." 

I'm not sure how that differs from the use you described prior.

Comment: @thesowismine the quote is from Wikipedia. Consider asking on the Wikipedia [Talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Apple_File_System) for clarification.