# What's special about /Applications on macOS Catalina?

Tags: catalina, notarization

I'm building a macOS binary to accompany a Chrome extension using the Chrome Native Messaging API. When the binary (unsigned, unnotarized) is in my Downloads folder, Chrome is not able to launch it. However, when I move the binary to `/Applications` (per https://stackoverflow.com/a/59710823/12581350), Chrome is able to launch it.

I was curious if anyone knows the reason why it's able to run from `/Applications` but not `~/Downloads`?

Comment: Probably the quarantine attribute. Try removing it from the binary in ~/Downloads.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is related to [App Translocation](https://lapcatsoftware.com/articles/app-translocation.html).

Yes, it’s related to the quarantine attribute. I believe it is the act of manually moving the file (not just moving it to /Applications/) which tells macOS that it is safe to open.

Comment: Maybe related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/372961/274087